# Create column based on condition with values from other column

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I am trying to create a new variable based on conditions and to take the value of other variables when the condition is met.
Basically, my data.frame looks like this:

```
    df <- data.frame (
  party=c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "D",
          "E", "F", "G", "H", "I","E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I",
          "J", "K", "L", "J", "K", "L", "J", "K", "L"),
  edate = c(1991, 1991, 1991, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998,
            2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010,
            1999, 1999, 1999, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2006, 2006, 2006),
  RRP = c(1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,
          0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0),
  absseats = c(0, 20, 30, 5, 25, 20, 0, 10, 28, 12,
               100, 50, 50, 25, 0, 120, 30, 75, 0, 15, 90, 60, 70, 5, 15,
               10, 20, 40, 30, 30, 10, 50, 10, 10),
  country=c(11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,
            10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,
            43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43),
  treat = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
             0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1,1,
             0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
```

What I want is a variable that takes the value of `edate` for which treat changes from 0 to 1 in each observation. And I want to assign value 0 when, for a specific "party", "treat" is always == 0 in the dataset.

Basically I want this:

```
first.treat <- c( 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 
              2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010,2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010,2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010,
              0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
ideal.df<- cbind(df,first.treat)
```

I tried different things, like different iteration of:

```
df%>%
  group_by(party)%>%
  arrange(edate)%>%
  mutate(first.treat = if_else(nrow = 1, edate, 0))
```

Here's a dput of my actual dataframe:

```
dput(df3[1:100,])
structure(list(country = c(61, 61, 52, 52, 61, 61, 61, 52, 52, 
52, 61, 61, 52, 52, 61, 61, 52, 52, 61, 61, 52, 52, 52, 61, 61, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 61, 61, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 52, 52, 52, 
62, 62, 62, 62, 51, 51, 51, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 23, 23, 23, 
23, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 
22, 22, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 15, 15, 15, 15, 171, 171, 63, 63, 
63, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 64, 64, 73, 43, 43), countryname = c("United States", 
"United States", "Northern Ireland", "Northern Ireland", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "Northern Ireland", "Northern Ireland", 
"Northern Ireland", "United States", "United States", "Northern Ireland", 
"Northern Ireland", "United States", "United States", "Northern Ireland", 
"Northern Ireland", "United States", "United States", "Northern Ireland", 
"Northern Ireland", "Northern Ireland", "United States", "United States", 
"Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "United States", 
"United States", "Finland", "Finland", "Finland", "Finland", 
"Finland", "Finland", "Northern Ireland", "Northern Ireland", 
"Northern Ireland", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "United Kingdom", 
"United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", 
"Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Luxembourg", "Luxembourg", "Luxembourg", 
"Luxembourg", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", 
"Denmark", "Denmark", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Netherlands", 
"Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", 
"Netherlands", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Iceland", 
"Iceland", "Iceland", "Iceland", "Mexico", "Mexico", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "New Zealand", "New Zealand", "Sri Lanka", 
"Switzerland", "Switzerland"), oecdmember = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), eumember = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), edate = structure(c(-17957, 
-17957, -17897, -17897, -16494, -16494, -16494, -16436, -16436, 
-16436, -15031, -15031, -14975, -14975, -13568, -13568, -13514, 
-13514, -12112, -12112, -11657, -11657, -11657, -10649, -10649, 
-9237, -9237, -9237, -9237, -9237, -9186, -9186, -9055, -9055, 
-9055, -9055, -9055, -9055, -8980, -8980, -8980, -8970, -8970, 
-8970, -8970, -8946, -8946, -8946, -8851, -8851, -8851, -8851, 
-8851, -8851, -8838, -8838, -8838, -8838, -8829, -8829, -8829, 
-8829, -8829, -8829, -8829, -8719, -8719, -8719, -8630, -8630, 
-8630, -8630, -8630, -8630, -8630, -8614, -8614, -8614, -8614, 
-8614, -8586, -8586, -8586, -8586, -8579, -8579, -8496, -8496, 
-8496, -8453, -8453, -8453, -8453, -8453, -8453, -8436, -8436, 
-8401, -8103, -8103), class = "Date"), date = c(192011, 192011, 
192101, 192101, 192411, 192411, 192411, 192501, 192501, 192501, 
192811, 192811, 192901, 192901, 193211, 193211, 193301, 193301, 
193611, 193611, 193802, 193802, 193802, 194011, 194011, 194409, 
194409, 194409, 194409, 194409, 194411, 194411, 194503, 194503, 
194503, 194503, 194503, 194503, 194506, 194506, 194506, 194506, 
194506, 194506, 194506, 194507, 194507, 194507, 194510, 194510, 
194510, 194510, 194510, 194510, 194510, 194510, 194510, 194510, 
194510, 194510, 194510, 194510, 194510, 194510, 194510, 194602, 
194602, 194602, 194605, 194605, 194605, 194605, 194605, 194605, 
194605, 194606, 194606, 194606, 194606, 194606, 194606, 194606, 
194606, 194606, 194607, 194607, 194609, 194609, 194609, 194611, 
194611, 194611, 194611, 194611, 194611, 194611, 194611, 194701, 
194710, 194710), party = c(61320, 61620, 52620, 52710, 61320, 
61620, 61621, 52320, 52620, 52710, 61320, 61620, 52620, 52710, 
61320, 61620, 52320, 52620, 61320, 61620, 52320, 52620, 52710, 
61320, 61620, 11220, 11320, 11420, 11620, 11810, 61320, 61620, 
14221, 14320, 14420, 14620, 14810, 14901, 52320, 52620, 52710, 
62320, 62420, 62620, 62951, 51320, 51420, 51620, 12220, 12320, 
12420, 12520, 12620, 12810, 23220, 23320, 23420, 23520, 13220, 
13320, 13410, 13420, 13620, 13952, 13953, 21320, 21420, 21520, 
22210, 22320, 22420, 22522, 22523, 22525, 22952, 32220, 32320, 
32410, 32420, 32520, 15220, 15320, 15620, 15810, 171301, 171601, 
63320, 63620, 63810, 31220, 31320, 31421, 31521, 31621, 31622, 
64320, 64620, 73330, 43320, 43321), partyname = c("Democratic Party", 
"Republican Party", "Unionist Party", "Nationalist Party", "Democratic Party", 
"Republican Party", "La Follette Progressive Party", "Northern Ireland Labour Party", 
"Unionist Party", "Nationalist Party", "Democratic Party", "Republican Party", 
"Unionist Party", "Nationalist Party", "Democratic Party", "Republican Party", 
"Northern Ireland Labour Party", "Unionist Party", "Democratic Party", 
"Republican Party", "Northern Ireland Labour Party", "Unionist Party", 
"Nationalist Party", "Democratic Party", "Republican Party", 
"Communist Party of Sweden", "Social Democratic Labour Party", 
"People’s Party", "Right Party", "Agrarian Party", "Democratic Party", 
"Republican Party", "Finnish People’s Democratic Union", "Finnish Social Democrats", 
"National Progressive Party", "National Coalition", "Agrarian Union", 
"Swedish People’s Party", "Northern Ireland Labour Party", 
"Unionist Party", "Nationalist Party", "Cooperative Commonwealth Federation", 
"Liberal Party of Canada", "Progressive Conservative Party", 
"Social Credit", "Labour Party", "Liberal Party", "Conservative Party", 
"Norwegian Communist Party", "Norwegian Labour Party", "Liberal Party", 
"Christian People’s Party", "Conservative Party", "Farmers’ Party", 
"Communist Party of Luxembourg", "Socialist Workers’ Party of Luxembourg", 
"Patriotic and Democratic Group", "Christian Social People’s Party", 
"Danish Communist Party", "Social Democratic Party", "Danish Social-Liberal Party", 
"Liberals", "Conservative People’s Party", "Justice Party", 
"Danish Union", "Belgian Socialist Party", "Liberal Party", "Francophone Christian Social Party and Flemish Christian People’s Party", 
"Communist Party of the Netherlands", "Labour Party", "Freedom Party", 
"Catholic People’s Party", "Anti-Revolutionary Party", "Christian Historical Union", 
"Reformed Political Party", "Italian Communist Party", "Italian Socialist Party", 
"Italian Republican Party", "Italian Liberal Party", "Christian Democrats", 
"United Socialist Party", "Social Democratic Party", "Independence Party", 
"Progressive Party", "Institutional Revolutionary Party", "National Action Party", 
"Australian Labor Party", "Liberal Party of Australia", "Country Party", 
"French Communist Party", "French Section of the Workers' International", 
"Radical Socialist Party", "Popular Republican Movement", "Rally for the French People - Gaullists", 
"Republican Party of Liberty - Conservatives", "New Zealand Labour Party", 
"New Zealand National Party", "United National Party", "Social Democratic Party of Switzerland", 
"Independents’ Alliance"), partyabbrev = c("Democrats", "Republicans", 
"UP", "NP", "Democrats", "Republicans", "", "NILP", "UP", "NP", 
"Democrats", "Republicans", "UP", "NP", "Democrats", "Republicans", 
"NILP", "UP", "Democrats", "Republicans", "NILP", "UP", "NP", 
"Democrats", "Republicans", "SKP", "SAP", "FP", "", "", "Democrats", 
"Republicans", "SKDL", "SSDP", "KE", "KK", "Maal", "RKP/SFP", 
"NILP", "UP", "NP", "CCF", "LP", "PCP", "Socred", "Labour", "", 
"Conservatives", "NKP", "DnA", "V", "KrF", "H", "", "KPL/PCL", 
"LSAP/POSL", "", "CSV/PCS", "DKP", "SD", "RV", "V", "KF", "RF", 
"DS", "BSP/PSB", "LP/PL", "PSC/CVP", "CPN", "PvdA", "PvdV", "KVP", 
"ARP", "CHU", "SGP", "PCI", "PSI", "PRI", "PLI", "DC", "So", 
"A", "Sj", "F", "PRI", "PAN", "ALP", "LPA", "CP", "PCF", "SIFO", 
"RRRS", "MRP", "RPF", "PRL", "Labour", "National", "UNP", "SPS/PSS", 
"LdU/AdI"), parfam = c(30, 60, 60, 70, 30, 60, 60, 30, 60, 70, 
30, 60, 60, 70, 30, 60, 30, 60, 30, 60, 30, 60, 70, 30, 60, 20, 
30, 40, 60, 80, 30, 60, 20, 30, 40, 60, 80, 90, 30, 60, 70, 30, 
40, 60, 95, 30, 40, 60, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 80, 20, 30, 40, 50, 
20, 30, 40, 40, 60, 95, 95, 30, 40, 50, 20, 30, 40, 50, 50, 50, 
95, 20, 30, 40, 40, 50, 20, 30, 60, 80, 30, 60, 30, 60, 80, 20, 
30, 40, 50, 60, 60, 30, 60, 60, 30, 30), coderid = c(101, 101, 
120, 120, 101, 101, 101, 120, 120, 120, 101, 101, 120, 120, 101, 
101, 120, 120, 101, 101, 120, 120, 120, 101, 101, 117, 117, 117, 
117, 117, 101, 101, 209, 208, 998, 208, 209, 209, 120, 120, 120, 
105, 105, 105, 105, 102, 102, 102, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
998, 104, 998, 104, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 104, 104, 
104, 326, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 326, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 
212, 212, 212, 212, 262, 262, 104, 104, 104, 106, 106, 106, 106, 
998, 106, 104, 104, 109, 229, 998), manual = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 998, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 998, 0, 998, 0, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 
999, 999, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 999, 999, 999, 999, 998, 999, 0, 0, 999, 
1, 998), coderyear = c(1981, 1981, 1980, 1980, 1981, 1981, 1981, 
1980, 1980, 1980, 1981, 1981, 1980, 1980, 1981, 1981, 1980, 1980, 
1981, 1981, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1981, 1981, 1983, 1983, 1983, 1983, 
1983, 1981, 1981, 1995, 1993, NA, 1993, 1995, 1995, 1980, 1980, 
1980, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1982, 1982, 1982, 1990, 1990, 1990, 
1990, 1990, 1990, NA, 1983, NA, 1983, 1983, 1983, 1983, 1983, 
1983, 1983, 1983, 1982, 1982, 1982, 2016, 1982, 1982, 1982, 1982, 
1982, 2016, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 
1998, 1998, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1982, 1982, 1982, 1982, NA, 1982, 
1982, 1982, 1980, 1991, NA), testresult = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.669, 0.341, NA, 
0.341, 0.669, 0.669, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.961, 0.961, 
0.961, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.94, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.94, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.975, 0.975, 0.975, 0.975, 0.88, 0.88, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.412, NA), testeditsim = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.471, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.471, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), voteest = c(0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 
NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0), presvote = c(34.2000007629395, 
60.2999992370605, NA, NA, 28.7999992370606, 54.0999984741211, 
16.6000003814697, NA, NA, NA, 40.7999992370605, 58.2000007629395, 
NA, NA, 57.4000015258789, 39.5999984741211, NA, NA, 60.7999992370605, 
36.5, NA, NA, NA, 54.7000007629395, 44.7999992370605, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 53.4000015258789, 45.9000015258789, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
77.869839, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), absseat = c(131, 303, NA, NA, 184, 247, 0, NA, NA, NA, 
166, 268, NA, NA, 313, 117, NA, NA, 334, 89, NA, NA, NA, 268, 
162, 15, 115, 26, 39, 35, 243, 190, 49, 50, 9, 28, 49, 15, NA, 
NA, NA, 28, 125, 67, 13, 393, 12, 199, 11, 76, 20, 8, 25, 10, 
5, 11, 9, 25, 18, 48, 11, 38, 26, 3, 4, 69, 17, 92, 10, 29, 6, 
32, 13, 8, 2, 104, 115, 25, 41, 207, 10, 9, 20, 13, 141, 4, 43, 
17, 12, 166, 90, 55, 158, 5, 70, 42, 38, NA, 48, 8), totseats = c(435, 
435, NA, NA, 435, 435, 435, NA, NA, NA, 435, 435, NA, NA, 435, 
435, NA, NA, 435, 435, NA, NA, NA, 435, 435, 230, 230, 230, 230, 
230, 435, 435, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, NA, NA, NA, 245, 
245, 245, 245, 640, 640, 640, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 51, 
51, 51, 51, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 202, 202, 202, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 556, 556, 556, 556, 556, 52, 
52, 52, 52, 147, 147, 74, 74, 74, 544, 544, 544, 544, 544, 544, 
80, 80, NA, 194, 194), progtype = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3), datasetorigin = c(30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 30, 30, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
30, 30, 30, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 110, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 110, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
30, 30, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 30, 10, 10
), corpusversion = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "2020-1", "", "", "", 
"", "", "2020-1", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), total = c(242, 
274, 26, 61, 272, 262, 139, 24, 54, 130, 275, 330, 58, 83, 93, 
390, 15, 68, 147, 193, 25, 129, 46, 258, 194, 52, 90, 63, 57, 
21, 109, 249, 205, 38, 139, 68, 91, 168, 144, 118, 34, 432, 75, 
308, 93, 567, 250, 326, 156, 501, 153, 47, 183, 94, 49, 107, 
118, 117, 128, 48, 64, 61, 133, 87, 136, 119, 52, 210, 125, 81, 
72, 151, 67, 64, 50, 84, 264, 126, 32, 48, 128, 198, 173, 52, 
141, 60, 277, 320, 74, 164, 464, 187, 287, 116, 365, 115, 734, 
120, 617, 112), rile = c(-9.917, 13.869, 22.8, 4, -8.824, -4.962, 
-28.058, -33.4, 3.9, -15.5, -13.091, -4.848, 26.7, -13.3, -1.075, 
-7.179, -45.6, 4.6, -15.646, 1.036, 0, -13.3, 11.1, -15.891, 
14.948, 9.6, -37.8, 9.5, 28, 23.81, -10.092, -0.803, -42.927, 
78.947, 21.583, 4.412, 3.297, 4.167, 15.2, -25.7, -64.7, -36.1, 
7.1, -8.8, -20.4, -31.3, -6.8, 15.2, -0.5, -32.8, -14.3, 12.6, 
15.7, 33, -42.857, -43.925, -2.542, 29.06, -21.2, -23, -15.7, 
16.4, -0.2, 6.8, -13.971, -13.5, 15.3, 30.1, -34.4, -19.8, 19.5, 
3.9, 21, 22.1, 56, -22.619, -31.818, -5.556, -9.375, 29.167, 
-1.7, -36.4, -9.4, 57.8, -18.44, -10, -16.4, 12.5, 41.9, 18.902, 
-14.44, 37.433, 48.432, 25, 25.479, -32.174, -3.542, -15.1, 10.049, 
-5.357), planeco = c(7.438, 1.825, 0, 0, 3.309, 2.29, 13.669, 
0, 0, 0, 6.909, 3.636, 2, 5.7, 12.903, 4.103, 12.9, 0, 11.565, 
4.663, 0, 7.1, 0, 8.915, 4.639, 1.9, 3.3, 3.2, 1.8, 0, 3.67, 
3.614, 5.854, 0, 5.755, 5.882, 3.297, 4.167, 0, 7, 0, 7, 2.8, 
2.7, 7.9, 13.9, 8.8, 4.8, 5.1, 14.4, 4.6, 2.1, 2.1, 0, 12.245, 
11.215, 2.542, 0.855, 2.4, 12.5, 6.3, 9.8, 1.6, 4.6, 7.353, 5.9, 
0, 8.5, 3.2, 4.9, 4.2, 3.4, 1.5, 1.6, 0, 3.571, 1.894, 0, 12.5, 
0, 4, 11.1, 2.9, 3.8, 6.383, 1.667, 6.2, 0.9, 0, 3.049, 7.543, 
2.139, 0, 1.724, 2.466, 15.652, 6.676, 10.1, 6.159, 9.821), markeco = c(10.331, 
9.124, 0, 0, 2.574, 12.595, 2.158, 0, 0, 0, 9.818, 9.091, 0, 
0, 9.677, 7.949, 0, 0, 11.565, 11.917, 0, 2, 0, 2.713, 15.464, 
1.9, 2.2, 6.4, 22.8, 19.048, 5.505, 6.024, 0, 0, 8.633, 1.471, 
9.89, 7.738, 0, 2, 0, 0.7, 9.9, 4, 8, 1.7, 10, 13.4, 0, 0.6, 
1.9, 4.2, 11.4, 1.1, 0, 0, 6.78, 5.128, 0, 0, 1.6, 9.8, 2.3, 
3.4, 3.676, 1.6, 15.3, 10, 2.4, 2.5, 12.5, 4.7, 7.5, 1.6, 0, 
0, 0.758, 0, 15.625, 0, 0.8, 1, 2.9, 3.9, 0.709, 8.333, 1.1, 
17.2, 28.4, 0, 1.94, 8.556, 0, 1.724, 9.863, 3.478, 7.357, 0.8, 
0.324, 7.143), welfare = c(2.066, 5.839, 4, 0, 8.088, 1.908, 
9.353, 33.3, 18.7, 31.7, 6.909, 2.121, 4.9, 19, 3.226, 5.897, 
26.7, 15.3, 10.884, 6.218, 4, 16.2, 2, 10.078, 3.093, 0, 33.4, 
14.3, 10.6, 0, 6.422, 4.418, 0.976, 0, 15.827, 4.412, 5.495, 
14.881, 7.1, 27.7, 58.8, 24.8, 9.9, 18.5, 22.8, 14.3, 9.2, 5.5, 
0.6, 14.8, 13.1, 19.2, 9.9, 9.6, 8.163, 16.822, 28.814, 8.547, 
15.6, 10.4, 12.5, 1.6, 0.8, 3.4, 12.5, 5.9, 5.8, 10, 14.4, 9.9, 
15.3, 15.2, 12, 9.6, 10, 8.333, 7.955, 1.587, 3.125, 8.333, 10.2, 
14.2, 2.3, 0, 12.057, 6.667, 14.2, 2.8, 0, 10.366, 9.698, 3.209, 
1.394, 0.862, 4.11, 16.522, 9.537, 7.5, 6.969, 15.179), intpeace = c(0.826, 
3.65, 7.9, 2, 3.676, 5.725, 4.317, 0, 3.9, 1, 3.636, 3.03, 2, 
0, 4.301, 4.103, 0, 1.2, 2.721, 1.554, 0, 4, 2, 1.55, 4.639, 
1.9, 5.6, 1.6, 0, 4.762, 8.257, 2.811, 13.659, 0, 0, 5.882, 0, 
0.595, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 5.7, 5.5, 4, 0.9, 3.2, 0.4, 0, 0, 
0.5, 0, 16.327, 3.738, 2.542, 6.838, 1.6, 4.2, 4.7, 1.6, 2.3, 
3.5, 8.088, 1.7, 3.8, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0.7, 0, 0, 2, 3.571, 3.03, 
0, 6.25, 0, 3.9, 2, 3.5, 0, 1.418, 1.667, 3.7, 0.3, 0, 3.659, 
3.448, 2.674, 0, 1.724, 0.548, 0, 0.136, 0, 0.486, 0), datasetversion = c("2020a", 
"2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", 
"2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", 
"2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", 
"2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", 
"2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", 
"2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", 
"2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", 
"2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", 
"2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", 
"2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", 
"2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", 
"2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", 
"2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", 
"2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", "2020a", 
"2020a"), id_perm = c("R2XX9S", "2D829W", "TSAEYI", "T4LHGH", 
"1YK8PA", "HO9FS1", "WFHDPR", "E7SUA1", "JOLKMR", "VZQDDH", "E5Z7JT", 
"Y6BLD9", "K4RKCF", "PZB7CH", "FQQ88F", "1N56G3", "QMGCFN", "CR6LFI", 
"XGWAUX", "SNXNNE", "YORPKV", "O6IQEJ", "Q9TAO9", "1PBVG5", "PF3F5D", 
"JN1LZH", "CMR7F6", "Z6OL6C", "YMKVN2", "U4SCRD", "1BDCF8", "AGY4FF", 
"Z8T6BR", "C1HESX", "PP1FLT", "VRQUU4", "BYBDN4", "TSWP7S", "87A16O", 
"M5KFE1", "RW9KFZ", "2V3SRK", "LHZGG9", "22FV9F", "RA5LSZ", "4GDSR7", 
"GSWOU2", "PM7TNC", "DYTZIJ", "VRYPF4", "45R9EV", "X3JG4S", "H9QEF1", 
"FJ5DYQ", "9V96FY", "JDKL6J", "9DP64U", "8NB5C3", "VONCDV", "HJW2XP", 
"ZCMMSZ", "K2B256", "G7GB47", "4A9XMW", "1QS6AT", "AOG6ZL", "AEY94Q", 
"F5PMRC", "DCQMXK", "H2U7BY", "AOP8QA", "VSFCG5", "PJNKSC", "WPEI98", 
"5IZK7H", "G9N2I8", "UBTI1E", "NUPH65", "PUN61D", "EYTEP7", "9STC2J", 
"GNUP8H", "B5JVLZ", "NDPIGY", "HBDI2K", "OQ4HYY", "GZWEAU", "8I1FL1", 
"3POAKF", "KTJQKG", "WSKKA7", "AXULXT", "VNYVIG", "DQFNM3", "CSKYBU", 
"OHUKIF", "HK132K", "XXUREL", "4ILMPJ", "TNUUY7"), RRP = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), pre.post = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), treat = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), first.treat = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), groups = structure(list(party = c(11220, 11320, 11420, 
11620, 11810, 12220, 12320, 12420, 12520, 12620, 12810, 13220, 
13320, 13410, 13420, 13620, 13952, 13953, 14221, 14320, 14420, 
14620, 14810, 14901, 15220, 15320, 15620, 15810, 21320, 21420, 
21520, 22210, 22320, 22420, 22522, 22523, 22525, 22952, 23220, 
23320, 23420, 23520, 31220, 31320, 31421, 31521, 31621, 31622, 
32220, 32320, 32410, 32420, 32520, 43320, 43321, 51320, 51420, 
51620, 52320, 52620, 52710, 61320, 61620, 61621, 62320, 62420, 
62620, 62951, 63320, 63620, 63810, 64320, 64620, 73330, 171301, 
171601), .rows = structure(list(26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 49L, 
    50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 
    33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 66L, 67L, 
    68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 
    90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 99L, 
    100L, 46L, 47L, 48L, c(8L, 17L, 21L, 39L), c(3L, 9L, 13L, 
    18L, 22L, 40L), c(4L, 10L, 14L, 23L, 41L), c(1L, 5L, 11L, 
    15L, 19L, 24L, 31L), c(2L, 6L, 12L, 16L, 20L, 25L, 32L), 
    7L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 85L, 
    86L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
"list"))), row.names = c(NA, 76L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

But I am not even able to get the first steps well.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write a small function which returns the `year` where `treat` values is 1 for the first time.

```
library(dplyr)

get_first_treat <- function(x, y) {
  inds = match(1, x)
  if(is.na(inds)) 0 else y[inds]
}
```

and apply this function for each `party` :

```
df %>%
  group_by(party) %>%
  mutate(first.treat1 = get_first_treat(treat, edate)) 

#   party edate   RRP absseats country treat first.treat
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1 A      1991     1        0      11     0        1998
# 2 B      1991     0       20      11     0        1998
# 3 C      1991     0       30      11     0        1998
# 4 A      1995     1        5      11     0        1998
# 5 B      1995     0       25      11     0        1998
# 6 C      1995     0       20      11     0        1998
# 7 A      1998     1        0      11     1        1998
# 8 B      1998     0       10      11     1        1998
# 9 C      1998     0       28      11     1        1998
#10 D      1998     0       12      11     1        1998
# … with 24 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't quite get what I'm looking for with this function, I get all zeros in first.treat

Comment: Are you using it on the data that you have shared ? On your data it does give me `first.treat` values which are not 0.

Comment: It's just larger, but iot's the same. In my data the object edate is  of type date with "%y-%m-%d", could that be the issue? Can't really make sense of this

Comment: That should not be the issue. Are you using `stats::lag` instead of `dplyr::lag` ? Try to append `dplyr::` in front of `lag` in the function and run the function and code again.

Comment: No, I tried it multiple times and it just doesn't work. I also tried detaching the package stats, but I can't because it is telling me that is imported by dplyr, which I need anyway for the second command you typed above

Comment: @AntVal Does it atleast work for you for the data you have shared?

Comment: No, because even there the row of party D, edate 1998 gets a zero for first.treat instead of "1998". I've uploaded a dput of the dataset I'm working with

Comment: But why would party D have 1998 as `first.treat` ? It has only one row so `treat` never changes from 0 to 1.

Comment: @AntVal n the data you have shared all the `treat` variables are 0 why would any of the `first.treat` be `1998` or any other `year` for that matter? You have asked `I want is a variable  that takes the value of edate for which treat changes from 0 to 1`. There is no treat which changes from 0 to 1. Can you check that?

Comment: Hi @Ronak, the dataset I shared are just the first 100 rows, but in the entire dataset there are multiple units changing treat from 0 to 1. You are right about the 1998 example, I am sorry, I was wrong and was not looking at it correctly

Comment: @AntVal I doubt if I am doing the same thing that you are asking. Can you create a small example and show expected output for it so that I can be sure that my code does the same thing that you are asking. Your original expected output for `df` gives an error. `arguments imply differing number of rows: 7, 36`

Comment: Sorry! I just corrected it now. It should work, please let me know if there's anything I can make clearer!

Comment: Why is "D" 1998? It has only one row so `treat` does not change from 0 to 1 in "D".

Comment: Right, now I see why I wasn't clear. Sorry! 
D's first.treat is 1998 because that is the first time treat == 1. What matters is when is the first date in which it has treat == 1 and not when it changes from 0 to 1. Is that clear now?

Comment: It works! thank you so much. Super kind of you to spend so much time with this.